# Android checkbox remove the box keep the text

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox

I am using a custom background color that changes depending on the state of the checkbox so my background property is already used. Most advices tell me to set the background to @null. I just want to keep the text and remove the box on the left.

I can already change the color of the background and the color of the text. I just want to remove the box.

```
<CheckBox
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_selector" 
        android:textColor="@color/checkbox_text"/>
```

[image: Unchecked - bakcground white, text black]

[image: Checked - background red, text white]

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I found it though, just need to add android:button="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that by the `button` property of the checkbox to change `the check drawable` like done below as per your requirement:

```
<CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:button="@drawable/cb_show_hide_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/checkbox_text"
            android:text="this is a checkbox"/>
```

Create the file in `drawable folder` with name `"cb_show_hide_selector.xml"` and add below following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_input_check" /> // for checked state
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_input_check" /> // for checked state
   <item android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> // for unchecked state
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example code checkbox dynamic no square button.**

```
private fun initCustomCheckbox(list : ArrayList<String>){
    for (i in list.indices) {
        val checkBox = AppCompatCheckBox(this)
        val params = FlowLayout.LayoutParams(
            FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 24, 24)
        checkBox.layoutParams = params
        checkBox.setPadding(24, 0, 24, 0)
        checkBox.id = i
        checkBox.tag = list[i]
        checkBox.text = list[i]
        checkBox.buttonDrawable = null
        checkBox.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.selector_check_box_empty_corner)
        checkBox.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.drawable.selector_text_color_primary))
        checkBox.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        checkBox.isClickable = true
        checkBox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 40f)
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                buttonView.setPadding(0, 0, 24, 0)
                buttonView.buttonDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_check)
            } else {
                checkBox.setPadding(24, 0, 24, 0)
                buttonView.buttonDrawable = null
            }
            buttonView.layoutParams = params
        }
        flowLayout.addView(checkBox)
    }
}
```

[Image Result above this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdAFQ.png)

**I hope this code it help you ^_^**

Comment: SO appreciated your intent to help. Would you care to add a description of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I offer you two different options:

1) You can set the checkbox to android: clickable="false", in the java code you call the instance checkbox.set clickable = false

2) Make a textView with set Visibility Gone, and when you click the checkbox, make the checkBox.set visibility("GONE") and the textView.set visibility("VISIBLE") that can fix your issue :D

I hope this can help you